# Craft 3: Get missing translations

Tags: localization, craft3

Is there an easy way in Craft 3 to get all missing translations for a certain language after they were piped through the translate TWIG filter?

```
{{ 'translate this text' | t }}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a PhpStorm plugin that adds “Missing translations”, “Unused translations” and “Translation message correctness” inspections to the IDE.

https://github.com/kalessil/yii2inspections

But unless I am missing something, it’s currently missing support for “Missing translations” inspections in Twig files. Both other features work well with Twig:

[image: Unused translations inspection]

Comment: thanks carlcs, the plugin looks good, but I would prefer having it in the cms. so that the customer, who is in most cases providing translations, can see missing translations and provide them themselves.